# 変数のスコープはfor内に入れてでもできるだけ狭くしたほうがいいか？

Tags: java, c++, c

初歩的な質問です．下記のようなコードがあったとします．

```
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
    int a = i;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

ここで，aはforの中でしか使用しません．しかし，スコープをできるだけ小さくしたほうがいいからといってforの中に入れて何回も宣言させるのは効率が悪い気がします．つまり，

```
int a;
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
     a = i;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

このようなプログラムとではスコープが大きくなる以外で何か不都合が起きたりするのでしょうか．

Comment: 型が同じ(int)であれば、`for(int i=0,a=0; i<100; ++i)` としても良いかと。

Comment: 過去質問について、尋ねたまま放置せず、回答を承認してください。未解決なのであれば疑問点について補足してください。

Comment: 「何回も宣言させる」とは？ そして、効率が悪いと考える理由はどのような理由ですか？ このような場合、新しいブロックスコープに入る度にスタックが拡張されるのではなくあらかじめ変数はスタックフレームに確保されるようになっているのが普通です。

Comment: 特に理由がなければ質問の言語(タグ）を一つ（例えば質問のコードがＣ＋＋なのでＣ＋＋）に絞った方が良い（回答者の労力が増す、混乱を招くなどのため）かと思います。

Answer (score 8):

C++言語にはコンストラクタ・デストラクタが存在します。

> ```
> int a = i;
> ```

は`i`で初期化されますが

> ```
> int a;
> a = i;
> ```

は空で初期化した上で、後から`i`をコピー・代入を行っています。また、デストラクターが実行されるタイミングも後者は`for`ループ終了直後ですが、前者はスコープを抜けるまでそのまま生き続けます。
単純な整数であれば違いはありませんが、汎用性を考慮すれば常に適切な変数スコープを意識すべきです。

これに関連して、C++言語では`for`だけでなく`if`や`switch`でも効率的な変数宣言できるように拡張されています。[if文とswitch文の条件式と初期化を分離](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp17/selection_statements_with_initializer.html)

Comment: Javaにデストラクタは無かったと思います。ファイナライザのことを言いたいと考えても、実行されるのは予期できないGC回収のタイミングなので、forループ終了直後とは限りませんし。

Comment: @らっしー 了解です、Javaへの言及は消すことにしました。

Answer (score 3):

> しかし，スコープをできるだけ小さくしたほうがいいからといってforの中に入れて何回も宣言させるのは効率が悪い気がします

メモリー効率的には変わらず実行速度的にも変わらず、可読性が向上するので積極的にスコープは小さくしましょう。

Answer (score 1):

質問文を読み、変数宣言にかかるコストに対して懸念が有る、というふうに理解しました。
私も以前同様の疑問を抱き、Java(Java5)とC(GCC 4.4.3)調べてみたことがあります。

- [ループ内で変数を宣言しない方が良いのか: 発火後忘失](http://feather.cocolog-nifty.com/weblog/2010/05/post-a00a.html)
  (※7年以上前の話なので、疑問の発端となったページは消えてしまっていますが…)

結論としては、ループ外で宣言しようが中で宣言しようが**効率は完全に同一である**、というものでした。
コンパイル後のバイトコード/アセンブリからは変数宣言した、という情報は無くなっていました。つまりローカル変数宣言にかかるコストはゼロです。